# Setup sendmail to relay to another smtp?

Tags: email, debian, sendmail, debian-lenny

My host provides an smtp server for sending mail. I want to setup sendmail to relay all emails to the hosts smtp server. How do you do that?

Comment: I can tell you the term you want is "smart host" but I don't know how to set it up in sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to answer your question without more context on your email environment.  That being said, the ***general*** steps would be:

1) Edit /etc/mail/sendmail.cf

2) Search for "DS"

You'll find a section that looks like this:

```
# "Smart" relay host (may be null)
DSrelay:[]
```

3) Put the downstream mail server IP in the square brackets.

4) Save changes. Bounce sendmail service.

Again, I have to reiterate that this is a general guideline. Your mileage may vary.

-M

Comment: Well normally I just point any program that needs to send email to the hosts smtp server but I didn't see an option for it in Anope and I read that it sends mail only by using sendmail.

Comment: One thing to note though is that since this is a Debian system, the sendmail binary might actually be part of exim and not sendmail (the sendmail.org mailer).